# Replace every 6th pipe in powershell

Tags: powershell, regex, string-manipulation

I realize I'm asking a similar question that was already asked and answered but I was not able to extrapolate the answer I needed since the regex and regex engine is different enough. I have hardware asset management logs which are pipe delimited but not are major delimited between endpoints.  The logs look like this:

```
|STATUS1|HOSTNAME1|IP1|MAC1|IS_WIRED1|STATUS2|HOSTNAME2|IP2|MAC2|IS_WIRED2|STATUS3|HOSTNAME3|IP3|MAC3|IS_WIRED3
```

What I would like to do is replace every 6th `|` with a carriage return to look like this:

```
|STATUS1|HOSTNAME1|IP1|MAC1|IS_WIRED1
|STATUS2|HOSTNAME2|IP2|MAC2|IS_WIRED2
|STATUS3|HOSTNAME3|IP3|MAC3|IS_WIRED3
```

The closest I've gotten selects each endpoint but I'm not quite sure how to utilize it using powershell.

```
[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|[^\|]*
```

I'm familiar with the replace command in PS and I'm imagining the end result would be something to this effect:

```
$hosts = $hosts -replace "<highspeed_low_drag_velcro_snap_regex_here>","\r\n"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JakeGould I would consider this a bit of a special case, because the OP is specifically seeking a PowerShell solution. Not only is it a different regex engine (.NET vs the PCRE that Notepad++ uses), but the replacement text is actually specified differently too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so this one's actually a little tricky. Arguably, regex isn't the best tool for the job, but it can do it.

```
-replace "(?<=^((\|[^|]*){5})+)\|","`n|"
```

---

I'll try to walk you through it:

- Your text has a section you want to *match* and a section you want to *replace*. Traditionally, regex replaces the entire search string, so you would use a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to specify some part of the search string to be cloned to the replacement output. Another way is to use a [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is what I've done here. PowerShell (.NET) is one of the few regex languages that supports *variable-length lookbehinds*, so we're in luck.
- The `(?<=)` section is a lookbehind. That means everything between the `=` and `)` is *matched* but not *replaced*. So `^((\|[^|]*){5})+` is used as a *condition* - the replacement will only happen if this bit matches the text before the intended replacement.
- The `^((\|[^|]*){5})*[^|]*` section can be summed up as "from the start of the line (`^`), match sets of five `|`s, and then match the text up to the next `|`".

  - The start of the line `^` is important - otherwise it can match anywhere in the line and there's no guarantee of how many `|`s came before.
  - Because `|` has a special meaning in regex, it needs to be escaped: `\|`. It does not need to be escaped when within a character class (`[]`).
  - `[^|]*` means "text up to the next `|`" — more technically, "as many characters other than `|` as possible" — more technically "repeat the `[^|]` character class as many times as possible, where that character class matches any character other than `|`".
  - `*` means "zero or more repetitions of the previous character, as many as possible"
  - So `(\|[^|]*)` means match `|` followed by as many characters as possible up till the next `|`. This will match `|text`
  - `{5}` means repeat the previous token exactly 5 times. It's exactly equivalent to copy-pasting the preceding token 5 times. So this will match `|text|text|text|text|text`
  - `((\|[^|]*){5})+` is one or more repetitions of that entire group. So it can match `|text|text|text|text|text`, `|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text`, etc. - in multiples of 5. The reason we use `+` instead of `*` is we don't want to match the empty group and replace the very first `|`.
  - And that makes the entire lookbehind, meaning it will only replace a `|` with exactly a multiple of 5 `|`s behind it, from the start of the line.
- Following that up with a `\|` as the actual text to replace, preceded by the matched lookbehind.
- Taking your example `|STATUS1|HOSTNAME1|IP1|MAC1|IS_WIRED1|STATUS2|HOSTNAME2|IP2|MAC2|IS_WIRED2|STATUS3|HOSTNAME3|IP3|MAC3|IS_WIRED3`, it will match the following:

  ```
  |STATUS1|HOSTNAME1|IP1|MAC1|IS_WIRED1**|**STATUS2|HOSTNAME2|IP2|MAC2|IS_WIRED2**|**STATUS3|HOSTNAME3|IP3|MAC3|IS_WIRED3
  ```

You'll notice here (if you haven't already) that you're actually trying to replace every *5th* `|` minus the first, not every *6th*. But the lookbehind method handles the "minus the first" situation fairly cleanly.

---

And now the replacement string.

- Because this is PowerShell, when we want `\n`, we actually want `` `n `` because the PowerShell escape character is `` ` ``. Note that this is only necessary in the replacement string; in the regex itself you would still use `\n` to pass that literal sequence to the regex engine.
- And because you have a leading `|` on every line, we need to add a new `|` after the new line. This works out because your original lines do not end with a `|`, therefore there is nothing to replace at the end of the lines, therefore we don't end up with an extra new line nor trailing `|`.

---

If you prefer the more traditional capture group method:

```
-replace "((?:[^|]+\|){4}[^|]+)\|","`$1`n|"
```

Figuring out how this works is left as an exercise to the reader ;) Tip: the `$1` backreference has to be escaped (with `` ` ``) because otherwise PowerShell interprets it as a shell variable.

Comment: Worked like a glove!  You also answered a few other questions about PS I had, you're a scholar and a gentleman!  Thanks!